# Como adicionar varios dicionarios usando o pickle para salvar em txt

Tags: python

Estou com o problema na hora de salvar um arquivo utilizando o modulo pickle, toda vez que faço a execução do programa ele reescreve sobre o dicionario ja existente. Ja tentei usar o shelve para subistituir mas não obtive exite.

Segue abaixo parte do algoritomo para melhor entedimento.

```
aluno = {'nome': str (nome), 'nota1':float(nota1), 'nota2':float(nota2), 'media': float(media), 'resultado': str(resultado)}
escola[aluno['nome']] = aluno
bancodd = open('escola_banco.txt', 'wb') #abrindo arquivo para modo de edicao
pickle.dump(escola,bancodd) #salvando arquivos
bancodd.close()
print ('Dados do aluno',nome,'salvos',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você não lê o arquivo original, ele sempre vai escrever um dicionário novo.

Você tem que, no começo da execução do seu programa, ler o arquivo que está no disco para um dicionário em memória, trabalhar com ele, atualizar, etc...e na hora de encerrar o programa, gravar o dicionário no disco.

Esse dicionário no disco sempre será um novo dicionário criado a partir do zero.  Tem formas de não re-escrever tudo? Tem - mas absolutamnte não vale a pena. Um dicionário com 10000 nomes será escrito em um tempo em torno de 1 segundo no disco, e as complicações para manter tudo sincronizado seriam várias.

A alternativa a esse fluxo de ler tudo pra memória, trablahar e gravar de volta é usar um banco de dados - seja SQL tradicional (e Python vem com o sqlite, não precisa instalar nem configurar nada), seja um banco NoSQL mais simples como o redis - que funciona quase como um dicionário "vivo".

Agora, uma coisa que você vai precisar fazer é agrupar seu código em *funções* . Você provavelmente já aprendeu sobre elas, então é hora de começar a exercitar o que aprendeu. Tendo uma função que lê o dicionário e uma que escreve o dicionário no arquivo, você pode fazer isso a todo momento que desejar, com apenas uma linha de código.  Da'i o restante da aplicação pode crescer para ter menus de inclusão de aluno, alteração de notas, etc.... e você só precisa chamar a função que grava o dicionário, com o código todo num lugar só.

Answer (score 1):

Você está copiando apenas uma referência do seu dicionário.

Para fazer uma [duplicata idêntica](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) do seu dicionário utilize a função `deepcopy()` do módulo `copy`:

```
import copy
...
escola[aluno['nome']] = copy.deepcopy(aluno)
...
```

Comment: Tentei usar esta maneira com o copy mas mesmo assim ele escreve em cima do arquivo ja salvo em txt.